# Ionic3 publish event throwing exception

Tags: ionic3

Has anyone observed, in Ionic 3, an exception thrown when publishing an event?

**Edit**: Upon closer inspection the exception has to do with the injected `Events` becoming `undefined` sometime after the constructor is first invoked. I'm wondering if there is a prerequisite that I am unaware of, e.g. in order to inject `Events`, it has to be done within a Component? In my situation, I am attempting to publish an event from a provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
...
@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
...
  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
    private events: Events,
  ) {
    console.log('Hello MyProvider Provider');
    console.log(`${ this.events } ${ typeof this.events }`) // [object Object] object
...
  private onUpdate(p: IAPProduct) {
    console.log(`${ this.events } `) // undefined
    this.events.publish('my event', p) // TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.events.publish')
  }
```

The only other detail that might be a factor is that `onUpdate` is being used as a callback during the execution of its constructor.

In advance, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The callback was making a reference to the wrong `this`, which I solved with `bind`:

```
    this.store.when(this.productId).updated(this.onUpdate.bind(this)) // from the constructor
...

  private onUpdate(p: IAPProduct) {
    console.log(`${ this.events } `) // [object Object]
    this.events.publish('my event', p) // no longer throws exception :)
  }
```